# How to programmatically wait for a write lock to finish?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using MongoDB, I have an operation that needs to drop a table, before writing to it again. Now, I know I can just use an update (which I am now, but it made me curious). Is there a way (in NodeJS) to check and wait for a lock to be released?

I know you can use [`db.currentOp()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp), however it's not a good idea to keep polling your locked DB for a status -- seems like a waste of resources.

For reference, here is a process I used where I encountered this issue:

```
db.collection("lastReadDate").drop();
db.collection(tableName).find().sort({"d": -1}).limit(1).toArray(function (err, arrayLastDate) {
    var lastReadCollection = db.collection("lastReadDate");
    lastReadCollection.insert({timestamp: arrayLastDate[0].d}, function (err, reply) {
            db.close();
    });
});
```

The issue was, the drop put a write lock on the table, so when it went to insert this new timestamp, it would skip over because the lock, and close the database connection.

So, since `drop` does not have any params or callbacks to handle processing, how would you wait for this lock to be released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, [`drop`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#drop) *does* take a callback parameter you can use for this.

```
db.collection("lastReadDate").drop(function(err) {
    db.collection(tableName).find().sort({"d": -1}).limit(1).toArray(function (err, arrayLastDate) {
        var lastReadCollection = db.collection("lastReadDate");
        lastReadCollection.insert({timestamp: arrayLastDate[0].d}, function (err, reply) {
                db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you serious? I didn't even try because the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) said " takes no arguments and will produce an error if called with any arguments." Do they not consider a callback an argument?

Comment: You're looking at the docs for dropping a collection in the shell, not node.js. See the link in my answer for the node.js driver docs.